# Why do we put $y = x^m$ as trial solution in Cauchy Euler Differential Equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$y = x^m$ is always a positive number. So why are we neglecting possible negative numbers by restricting $y = x^m?$
Is there any restriction that the solution of a DE will always be positive?

Comment: Why do you seem to think that $x^m\gt0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Cauchy-Euler differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) is a homogeneous linear differential equation. This implies that any linear combination of solutions is again a solution. Now it has turned out that often functions of the form $x\mapsto x^r$ for some constant $r\in{\mathbb C}$ are solutions of a given such equation. It is therefore reasonable to find the set $\{r_1,r_2,\ldots, r_m\}$ of acceptable $r_i$ for a given equation. One then can say that all functions
$$y(x):=\sum_{i=1}^m c_i x^{r_i},\qquad (x>0, \>c_i\in{\mathbb C})$$
are solutions. Sometimes it will be necessary to sieve out the real functions among these.